# Recurring Magento search term attack

Tags: magento, search, bots

We are recording an extraordinarily high number of searches for a specific search term:-  "biscru" or "Ticru"   (63,000 times in the past 2 months).  The apache log is showing these requests as coming from Googles servers but I find this hard to believe and suspect the IP address is being spoofed.

Apache Log Example:-

```
rawliving.eu:66.249.72.227 - - [06/Jul/2013:01:25:09 +0100]
"GET /catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=47&dir=desc&limit=25&mode=list&order=event_date&p=6
&q=%22biscru%22+OR+%22Ticru%22
HTTP/1.1" 200 20587 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Clearly blocking 66.249.72.227 is not a option as it is a valid google address so can anyone suggest what options we have to prevent this distortion and maybe identify where these requests are coming from and why?

Any advice gratefully received.
Lee

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that Google would crawl a search engine page if it is linked to anywhere on the internet. Update your robots.txt file and add the robots tag to your layout XML file to tell Google to leave this page alone.

Comment: We are also having the same problem over 350,000 hits on one search term. I wondered the same about a possible DOS, but after doing some digging we are not the only ones suffering from this and others have complained. I don't think simply stopping Google Bot from crawling the page is the answer, after all I want my search pages indexed. We're trying to put NOFOLLOW on any links returned from our search page that are not product related to see if this corrects the issue (e.g. Category and layered navigation filters).

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your layout-xml definition e.g. local.xml

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <catalogsearch_advanced_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_index>
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

Check if the problem remains after a few days... or just use a robots.txt file to block the catalogsearch urls from being indexed.

Comment: This just blocks Google robots - I believe the question is about a type of DDoS attack which fakes itself as a Google bot.